# Can one rely on Paypal IPN solely to record purchases?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm setting up a simple 'buy now' transaction from a website with these major steps:

1. Select product from price list
2. Review selection (amounts, tax etc)
3. Process Payment on Paypal
4. Receipt / Thank you

At the moment, i'm storing a database record in step 2 - which potentially means there will be a number of records where no payment is received as people decide not to go ahead with their purchase after all.  These records are of no real use since i'll use Google Analytics to track how successful the checkout flow is.

I'm using Paypal IPN to verify the authenticity of the payments and log them against the records inserted at step 2 - however, could I feasibly rely solely on the data from the IPN transactions to populate the database in the first place, thus removing the need to store them at step 2 and have to do database cleanup to remove transactions that never completed?

I personally can see no reason why I wouldn't - the IPN contains all the data I need about the payment and probably more besides, and Paypal will resend IPNs for several days if they don't go through first time due to server glitchery, but am I missing anything else important?

Obviously the number one consideration is that no transactions get lost or aren't logged so that no customer unhappiness ensues!

Comment: On reflection, I think the answer to my question might be "Yes, you can - but no, you shouldn't".

Comment: Offering a small bounty to see if there are any other suggestions/answers out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to do a 2 way validation like you have.

You save the order info (total, quantity) before the user leaves your system towards paypal. When ipn come back you validate the request (it must be from paypal ip or whatever), you validate that it's a successful transaction then your step 2 enters the scene. You validate if the total returned from paypal ipn is the same with the total that was saved before the user left (Paypal sometime may return partial payments, the user may grab the post data and do his own post from a modified html with a lower `total` set). Step 2 should also store the user_id of the buyer so you must compare that too.

here's a sample layer (no programming language just a dummy code):

```
if request comes from paypal:
    #   query the order
    if order.total == request.total && order.user_id == request.custom:
        payment may come in...
```

Comment: This is what i've done in the end, I check the transaction record exists, the total against the IPN total, and that the currency is GBP.  I will do a database cleanup to remove any incomplete orders after a week or so.

Comment: this is what I do too. good strategy... IPNs can be a bit flakey at times - only other thing I do is to check the database to make sure the transaction hasn't already been processed. It happens that we get duplicate IPNs even though they are dealt with correctly. grumble grumble...

Answer (score 3):

As the designer and administrator of a system that has processed over 600,000 PayPal payments in the last three years - relying exclusively on IPN will allow some errors to slip through the cracks.

Real data:

```
        Total transactions   No IPN    Invalid IPN  Duplicate IPN
year 1      170,000 +          2           101           0
year 2      205,000 +         54            15           3
year 3      230,000 +         20            24          13
```

Fortunately, our system is structured with PDT (Payment Data Transfer) as a 'backup' so we didn't lose any transaction data or have unhappy customers.  Note:  PDT can't be relied upon exclusively either - in fact, early this year, there was a major problem with the reliability of PDT returns.

The most common 'invalid' IPN returns are an HTML error page or truncated results ...  I can provide samples if desired.

The best choice is a combination of both IPN and PDT (with your 'cart' data stored in your DB as you are).  Either the IPN processs or the PDT process can create the transaction (and delete the 'cart' data record in the DB).  The second process to arrive will then not have a 'cart' entry from which to record a transaction.

NOTE: - as you noted in your final solution to use a custom field - be aware there is a length limitation to the custom field and it can be truncated upon being returned to you.

Answer (score 1):

I have not relied solely on IPN to do this, but PayPal will log failures to contact your server if it fails and is supposed to retry later, although I only ever had failures in development and never verified the retry. I just trust them on this one.

Comment: A few hours after writing the question and staring at more code, I thought of one potential issue - checking the data in the IPN to ensure a match up of the amount & currency of the transaction.  If its not stored, nothing to match against - so someone could generate a paypal transaction with a valid IPN but for the incorrect amount of money?  What say you?

Comment: I guess that depends on what you are selling. If the price is constant, that's fairly easy to check. If there is enough information for you to calculate back the totals based on selected items, it still works.Keeping information to double-check does seem like the safer route.

Comment: The site is basically selling 'credits' which can then be used for uploading or downloading content.  I've decided to go down the route of logging the information pre-payment (basically which product and what the price was at the time of purchase) and sending a custom field to paypal so that we can identify it when the IPN comes in, it just seems safer that way.

Answer (score 1):

For a typical e-commerce site, yes you can -- it's fairly reliable.  If nuclear reactors will melt down and people will die, then no you can't -- I've seen problems with it, but very infrequently.

Comment: We're assuming he's a nuclear power plant website coder then? xD

Comment: @Cyclone yes -- PHP's true niche.

Comment: Dammit, my latest project was a nuclear safety system that relied on payments from local residents to keep it switched on, I thought I was onto a money-spinner right there :-)  Seriously though, see my comment on the other answer - also, another thought if someone sends money directly through paypal (why would they? but they could..) without storing web transactions before we'd not know if that money was to pay for a transaction we're expecting or just a random gift...?

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a number of eCommerce sites, and in practice you always want to record what you can in case of any 'accidents'. You own data is probably more informative.

Like you said, yes you can do this, but I would suggest that it is not a great idea.